# Best way to do AS (autonomous system) lookup in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios

What's the best way to do AS (autonomous system) lookup in an app for iPhone?

Looks like iPhone apps don't have root access, so I can't call "dig" or "whois" from the app using `system()` or `popen()`.

Comment: I found the source code for whois.c (http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/adv_cmds/adv_cmds-149/whois/whois.c).  Now the question is how can I integrate this into my object C project, how can I call the main() from the ViewController?

Comment: You should probably use a web-service for this, instead of trying something like `popen` or `system`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create a header file "whois.h" with following:

extern int whois(int argc, char *argv[]);

2) Change the Function Name from main to any name:

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

to:

int
whois(int argc, char *argv[])
{

3) In your object-c .m file, import whois.h

Now you can call that function:

whois();